# One to many and scope in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my Ruby on Rails application I have the following models:

```
class Notification < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :museum, touch: true
  has_many :arts
end

class Museum < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :notifications
end

class Art < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :notification
  has_one :museum
end
```

And now my problem is that I can associate art from a different museum with notification with different museum but this is wrong. Is there any Rails way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

```
class Notification < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :arts # there is relation to arts
  has_many :museums,
    through: :arts # you can access museums only through arts, there is no direct connection
end

class Museum < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :arts # in museum you have arts
  has_many :notifications,
    through: :arts # you can access notifications, but only through arts
end

class Art < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :notification # art belongs to notification, will save notification_id if one exist for this art 
  belongs_to :museum # art belongs to museum
end
```

Rails [has many through relation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association), check this also

Comment: But notification cant have has_many :museums, it must have belongs_to :museum

Comment: Because now I can find any art and associate with any notification in this style:
notification.arts << art

Comment: Your model is bad designed, that is main issue. Your relation between `Notification` and `Museum` is not natural. This is issue of ternar relation, but you have designed it bad.